# Difference between UriTemplate parameters and method parameters

Tags: c#, wcf, c#-4.0, uritemplate

Consider the code

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate="/{memId}/{username}")]
[ServiceContract]
void Method(string strMemId,string strUname)
{
// my code goes here
}
```

Are the parameters present in the UriTemplate,the same to the method parameters?
If not, when will they be needed/required?

Thanks.
Any inputs appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the method parameters are passed through the Uri, the order of transfer, you must set Uritemplate. your situation is would be `(UriTemplate = "/ {strMemId} / {strUname}" )`
If you do not, the program will not understand where to find the desired parameter

Comment: So, Is UriTemplate necessary when having webHttpBinding as our primary binding mehanism?

Comment: Not only with this binding. This is a  template that represents the URI